# website is not hosting and deploy on the firebase (the default index.js which contain documentation of firebase is hosting)

Tags: reactjs, firebase, next.js, firebase-hosting

This is my package.json file

```
{
  "name": "react-portfolio",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "10.4.14",
    "eslint": "8.42.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "13.4.4",
    "firebase": "^10.7.2",
    "next": "13.4.4",
    "postcss": "8.4.24",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.9.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.12.1",
    "tailwindcss": "3.3.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "firebase-tools": "^13.1.0"
  }
}
```

These are the folders I used the out directory as the public directory:

[image: screenshot of my folders I used the out directory as the public directory]

```
npm install -D firebase-tools

node_modules/.bin/firebase login
node_modules/.bin/firebase init

npm run build 

node_modules/.bin/firebase deploy --only hosting
```

I tried installing firebase tools globally, but it is still not working.